# Append something to the data sent with `<form method="post">` with html?

Tags: html, forms, post

Is there a way to append/preppend something to the data sent with `<form method="post">` with html?
Explanation:
a user enters "Hello World" into a `<textarea>` element with `name="textArea1"`. Is it now possible to write the html so that the server receives:

```
$_POST['textArea1'] == 'This sentence was prepended with html. Hello World';
```

I know how to do this with js, I am just curious if there is a way to do this with just plain html. If this is not possible, is there a way to send along the script name that made the post request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're good using PHP to append/prepend, use this:

```
$var = 'prepend... '.$_POST['textArea1'].'... and append';
```

As you stated in your post it's possible with JS. It's not possible with only HTML.

Comment: Yes use dot to concatenate string as Mooseman did and use single quote for better parsing.

Comment: PHP is not an option. I won't know in advance what script will receive the data since I am using autoloading.

Comment: @DudeOnRock 1) Why did you use `$_POST['textArea1']` if you're not using PHP? 2) It's not possible with only HTML.

Comment: @Mooseman: That is what I am asking: IS it possible. I used `$_POST['textArea1']` to clarify what I want to receive inside my php script. The script can't know what I want to append to the data.

Comment: Simple answer: you can't with only HTML. JS? Yes. PHP? Yes.

Comment: @Mooseman: I removed my downvote, since your answer now addresses my question. Thanks!

Comment: @DudeOnRock Thanks. Please mark my answer as "best answer" for future users.